# Getting error that Element doesn't exist (PHP->JS) when trying to remove div

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I'm seeing an error in Chrome's console that says

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null at (index):69`

Which I understand that error... It's telling me the element doesn't exist. The problem is that the element ***does*** exist.

Here's the PHP code snippet I'm testing:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE["Qrtg54562dgfdsw@234"])){
   print "We've got you down at " . $_COOKIE['Qrtg54562dgfdsw@234'] . "!";
   print "<br> Thanks for showing interest. You'll be getting contacted by 
   someone very soon!";
   print '<script type="text/javascript">'; 
   print 'document.getElementById("removethiswhen").style.display= "none";'; 
   print '</script>'; 
}else{...
```

Now, the html with the Div element with the same ID:

```
<div style="margin=0;" id="removethiswhen">
   <form action = "" id="emailsub" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="email" placeholder=" Your Email">
     <br><br>
     <div onClick='document.getElementById("emailsub").submit();' style=" 
     cursor:pointer; padding-left: 45.85; padding-right: 45.85;" 
     class="button">Submit</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I immediately assume it's a syntax error I'm not seeing, but then when I copy and paste the js function in Chrome's console

```
'document.getElementById("removethiswhen").style.display= "none";'
```

the div disappears! [here is a photo proving the JS is working in the console]

[image]

Now, I've tried using the sleep() function  right where the php tag starts in case the PHP is working too fast for the DOM to read it's elements (I'm throwing shots into the dark at this point because to be honest that doesn't make any sense at all)

This issue is occuring on multiple browsers.

Comment: Your JS code is running before your div has appeared in the DOM. Put it in a `window.onload` function.

Comment: ...or rather than `.onload` just make sure the `<script>` element from your PHP appears *after* the `<div>` in question.

Comment: I moved the entire php code block down appending the <body> tag and now it is removing the div. Thank you nnnnnn and Zenoo for the quick answers!